# How can I duplicate table entries while changing one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with entries that looks like this,

```
| ALP  | Amethyst Light        | Pear                 |    8 | ss    |        7 |   0.38 |    5 |
```

I would like to copy this, and every other entry while adding a letter to the end of the code, based on the current code. I would like to add the letter G to the end of the code so it says ALPG

This gets me most of the way there, [Copy a table change values of 1 column and insert it in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724318/copy-a-table-change-values-of-1-column-and-insert-it-in-the-same-table), however I would like to be able to keep the original value but add a letter to end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into t(code, <list of rest of columns>)
    select concat(code, 'G'), <list of rest of columns>
    from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `+ 'G'` to the column when you insert it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you using `CONCAT`:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Col1, Col2, ...)
SELECT CONCAT(Col1,'G'), Col2,...
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is a little lacking on details, but given the other question you reference, it sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
insert into your_table (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8)
select concat(col1,'G'),col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Use **XAMPP** tool .it is multiplatform tool like mysql , sql, perl ...etc .so u cna able to insert data using this tool very simple.